# Reading CHUID from military CAC with Grabba on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, smartcard, rfid

I am attempting to read a CHUID from a military ID CAC with Grabba on iOS 8.1.

I am expecting to get successful responses. First I run SelectPIV. I get 0x61 & 0x18 as status words. Then I use status word 2 from the response to install a Get Response command.

I am expecting a 0x61 on Get Response. Instead I receive 0x69 and 0x85 . Then I run a selectCHUID command. I expect to receive 0x61. Instead I receive 0x6D, which my reference code labels as a "Bad Instruction".

I receive the same status words for these 3 commands no matter the order I send them in. I get the same result for Get Response using the default initialization and the customized initialization with installGetResponseCommand with the second status word LE from the response SW2.

My company has had success with this code on other platforms with other device scanners on the same CAC cards. It is only with Grabba on iOS that we are seeing these results.

```
- (void)setupAPDUCommands {
    unsigned char selectBytes[] = { 0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00};

    self.selectPIVCommand = [[GRGrabbaCommandAPDU alloc] initWithCLA:0x00
                                                            INS:0xA4
                                                             P1:0x04
                                                             P2:0x00
                                                           Data:[NSData dataWithBytes:selectBytes length:9]
                                                          Error:nil];

    unsigned char chuidBytes[] = { 0x5C,
        0x03,
        0x5F,
        0xC1,
        0x02};


    self.CHUIDCommand = [[GRGrabbaCommandAPDU alloc] initWithCLA:0x00
                                                         INS:0xCB
                                                         P1:0x3F
                                                         P2:0xFF
                                                       Data:[NSData dataWithBytes:chuidBytes length:5]
                                                            Le:0
                                                           Error:nil];

    self.getResponseCommand = [[GRGrabbaCommandAPDU alloc] initWithCLA:0x00
                                                              INS:0xC0
                                                               P1:0x00
                                                               P2:0x00
                                                             Data:nil
                                                               Le:0x02 Error:nil];
}


- (UInt8)exchangeAPDUCommand:(GRGrabbaCommandAPDU *)command {
    self.promptLabel.text = [command.data description];
    NSLog(@"***EXCHANGING APDU COMMAND***");
    NSLog(@"CLA:  %@", [self stringFromUint:command.cla]);
    NSLog(@"INS:  %@", [self stringFromUint:command.ins]);
    NSLog(@"P1:   %@", [self stringFromUint:command.p1]);
    NSLog(@"P2:   %@", [self stringFromUint:command.p2]);
    NSLog(@"LC:   %@", [self stringFromUint:command.lc]);
    NSLog(@"Data: %@", command.data);
    NSLog(@"LE:   %@", [self stringFromUint:command.le]);

    self.currentCommand = command;
    NSError *error;
    self.session = [[[GRGrabba sharedGrabba] smartcard] startSession:&error] ;

    [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Session started: %@", error.description]];
    GRGrabbaResponseAPDU *response = [[GRGrabbaResponseAPDU alloc] initWithData:nil SW1:0 SW2:0];
    NSError *e2;

    [self.session exchangeAPDUCommand:command withResponse:response error:&e2];

    NSLog(@"***APDU COMMAND EXCHANGED***");
    NSLog(@"SW1:  %@", [self stringFromUint:response.sw1]);
    NSLog(@"SW2:  %@", [self stringFromUint:response.sw2]);

    [self processSmartCardScan:response];

    return response.sw1;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self initializeGrabba];
    [self setupAPDUCommands];
}

- (void)initializeGrabba {
    GRGrabba *grabba = [GRGrabba sharedGrabba];
    grabba.barcode.delegate = self;
    grabba.buttons.delegate = self;
    grabba.smartcard.delegate = self;
}

- (IBAction)selectPivTapped {
    [self exchangeAPDUCommand:self.selectPIVCommand];
}
- (IBAction)readCHUIDTapped {
    [self exchangeAPDUCommand:self.CHUIDCommand];
}
- (IBAction)getResponseTapped {
    [self exchangeAPDUCommand:self.getResponseCommand];
}


- (void)installGetResponseCommand:(GRGrabbaResponseAPDU *)response {
    self.getResponseCommand = [[GRGrabbaCommandAPDU alloc] initWithCLA:0x00
                                                                   INS:0xC0
                                                                    P1:0x00
                                                                    P2:0x00
                                                                  Data:nil
                                                                    Le:response.sw2
                                                                 Error:nil];

}

- (void)processSmartCardScan:(GRGrabbaResponseAPDU *)response {
    self.statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i %i %@", response.sw1, response.sw2, response.rData];
    if (self.currentCommand == self.selectPIVCommand) {
        [self installGetResponseCommand:response];
    } else if (self.currentCommand == self.CHUIDCommand) {
        self.mutableScanData = [NSMutableData data];
        if (response.sw1 == 0x61 || response.sw1 == 0x90) {
            [self.mutableScanData appendData:response.rData];
            [self exchangeAPDUCommand:self.getResponseCommand];
        }
    } else if (self.currentCommand == self.getResponseCommand) {
        if (response.sw1 == 0x61) {
            //recreate get response dynamically
            [self.mutableScanData appendData:response.rData];
            [self exchangeAPDUCommand:self.getResponseCommand];
        } else if (response.sw1 == 0x90) {
            [self.mutableScanData appendData:response.rData];
            [self processExtractedSmartCardData:self.mutableScanData];
        } else {
            [self alertUserOfFailedScan];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the last two bytes on the SELECT PIV APDU:

```
unsigned char selectBytes[] = { 0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00};

self.selectPIVCommand = [[GRGrabbaCommandAPDU alloc] initWithCLA:0x00
                                                        INS:0xA4
                                                         P1:0x04
                                                         P2:0x00
                                                       Data:[NSData dataWithBytes:selectBytes length:7]
                                                      Error:nil];
```

And Le should be zero on the get response command.

Comment: Consider elaborating a bit more.